# xrandr - Issue when scaling monitor on the left, but works on the right

Tags: linux, cinnamon, manjaro, xrandr, monitors

I have an integrated eDP1 monitor (2560x1440) and an external HDMI1 monitor (1920x1080).

If I  want my external monitor on the right side, this command works as expected :
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP1`.

However, if I want the external monitor on the left side, this is not working :
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --scale 2x2 --left-of eDP1`

When I do this, half of my integrated screen also appear on the external monitor.

I have no idea if that's a bug or simply a misconfiguration on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux does not take the scaling into account for the `--left-of` option. Instead of `--left-of` I would suggest `--output eDP1 --auto --pos 3840x0`. This moves the `eDP1` screen to the right border of the `HDMI1` screen.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --scale 2x2 --output eDP1 --auto --pos 3840x0
```

Comment: Fantastic ! I finally have a solution to my problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: It would be great to know why doesn't it take scaling into account for --left-of option :)